# R chi squared test significant results one category empty

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

I'm looking for the relationship between two binary factors eg. home-ownership and citizenship. In some segments, I don't have any observations in a category eg. no home-owners.

Using the function chisq.test() from the stats package, why do I still get significant results? I would expect the chi square calculations to come back null if an entire column of the table is empty.

[image]

Comment: Not a coding question. Voting to migrate to Cross Validated where the stats experts are.

Comment: On a coding note: I get a different result `chisq.test(matrix(c(0, 1, 87, 17), ncol = 2))` returning a p-value of 0.381, which is in line with what you correctly surmised (i.e. cannot reject the null).

Comment: This is a 1 column data set since the only value for test_factor is 0. It could be coded as `chisq.test(c(87, 17))` which returns the value shown in the picture. The null hypothesis is that the number of observations in ret_factor==0 is the same as the number of observations in ret_factor==1. Clearly they are different 87 vs 17 so the null hypothesis should be rejected as it is.